# Remove from list from other list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I have list which contain other lists (2 levels only)

```
((S U S U R) (S U S R) (S U R))
```

How to remove the lists from list which contains some pairs, the same combination of 2 element on first ans second position in list or 3th and 4th position (in my example "S U") and to return `((S U S R) (S U R))`

I need to transform

`((S U S U R) (S U S R) (S U R))`   to =>  `((S U S R) (S U R))`

`((S U R S U) (S U S R) (S U R))`   to =>  `((S U R S U) (S U S R) (S U R))` - do not change, because here is pairs have S U, R S, U and no S U 2 or more times

Comment: You can use remove-if, lambda, equalp and subseq.

Answer (score 2):

### [`REMOVE-IF`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rm_rm.htm)

```
(remove-if #'oddp '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> (2 4)
```

### [`LAMBDA`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/s_lambda.htm)

```
(funcall (lambda (x) (string x)) :example)
=> "EXAMPLE"
```

### [`EQUALP`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_equalp.htm)

```
(equalp '(S U) (list 's 'u))
=> T
```

### [`SUBSEQ`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_subseq.htm)

```
(subseq '(a b c d) 0 3)
=> (A B C)
```

Careful:

```
(subseq '(a b c d) 0 10)
=> ERROR
```

You can also use [`LENGTH`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_length.htm) to get the size of a list. You could also use following functions...

### [`NTHCDR`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_nthcdr.htm)

```
(nthcdr '(s u s u r u) 5)
=> (U)
```

### [`LDIFF`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_ldiffc.htm)

```
(let ((list '(a b c d)))
  (ldiff list (nthcdr 10 list)))
=> (A B C D)

(let ((list '(a b c d)))
  (ldiff list (nthcdr 2 list)))
=> (A B)
```

### What you want to do

You want to remove elements from the input list that satisfy the following predicate: given a list, a subset of this list is equal to `(S U)` *(see comments)*.

Your code will looks like this:

```
(defun remove-s-u-at-pos-3 (list)
  (remove-if (lambda (...) ...) list))
```

You need to extract a part of each visited list and compare it to `(S U)`.

Comment: Ok so you compare two subsets of each list, but careful about short lists